# Using Laravel Goutte package for scraping

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, goutte

But i have face the problem for scraping for my targeted site
It shows me an error

```
"file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:140770FC

:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol"
```

My code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Goutte\Client;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\library\simple_html_dom;

class WebScraperController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //  Create a new Goutte client instance
        $client = new Client();

        //  Hackery to allow HTTPS
        $guzzleclient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'timeout' => 60,
            'verify' => false,
        ]);
        
        // Create DOM from URL or file
        $html = new \Htmldom('https://www.example.com/');

      
        foreach ($html->find('img') as $element) {
            echo $element->src . '<br>';
        }

        // Find all links
        foreach ($html->find('a') as $element) {
            echo $element->href . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not using Guzzle in that code.

Comment: i am using Guzzle client

Comment: No, you are using `Htmldom` And that makes request to a ssl web page with the 80 port. Thats why you are getting that error.

Comment: can you guide me how can i use it?

Comment: Just put like this, may be it works!!:) `$guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array(
                          'curl' => array(
                              CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
                              CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
                          ),
                        ));`